# WordPress - Specify different images as the thumbnail and original file

Tags: php, wordpress, media

Sometimes the autogenerated thumbnails do not meet the requirements. What I am searching for is a solution to specify a completely different file as the thumbnail.

Just like a new uploader within the media element itself and below the caption, title etc fields where I can select another file to be used as the thumbnail.

Is this possible? Can anyone guide me in the right direction? Searched a lot but to no avail.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plenty of Wordpress plugins such as "Regenerate Thumbnails" or "WP-CLI".
Here is the [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).
By this plugin, you can regenerate Thumbnails all thumbnail sizes for one or more images that have been uploaded to your Media Library.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for being unclear. I actually dont want to regenerate or alter autogenerated thumbails but have completely different images as thumbs. For instance if I have fully red image I want a fully green thumbnail. Currently I use toolset to add the according ulpoad meta to the attachment CPT but I did not find any approriate functions.php solutions (and prefer those). :)